# Sobre índices de array

Tags: javascript

Em javascript, como faço para acessar o índice de uma array que está contido dentro de outro array? Por exemplo:

```
var x= [ [ 1,2  ] , [ 1,3  ] , [ 1,4  ] ];
```

Como faria para acessar o índice correspondente do vetor `[1,4]` que está contido dentro do array `x`?

Answer (score 4):

Podes usar `[]` consecutivos para aceder a propriedades mais profundas de uma array (e também o mesmo em objetos).

Exemplo:

```js
var x = [
  [1, 2],
  [1, 3],
  [1, 4]
];
var quatro = x[2][1];
console.log(quatro); // 4
```